# Quickblox iOS: chatRoomDidEnter called multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, chat, quickblox

This is my third Quickblox question in a row and I hope someone answers me.

As usual, Quickblox's documentation confuses me again.

I am using following code to create / join a room:

```
[[QBChat instance] createOrJoinRoomWithName:roomName membersOnly:NO persistent:YES];
```

Upon login, when I call this method, following delegate is called:

```
- (void)chatRoomDidEnter:(QBChatRoom *)room
```

However this is called once again - probably when other user calls the above statement.

Why, again, why such things keep happening?
Isn't it intended for current user only?
The delegate method's documentation says:

> Fired when you did enter to room

Then why this unexpected behavior?

Also I keep getting the age old messages with following log:

```
<Warning>: QBChat/didReceiveMessage: <message xmlns="jabber:client" id="1407872706.569180" from="11447_en@muc.chat.quickblox.com/1233710" to="1233710-11447@chat.quickblox.com/56FEC1BB-71E8-4CDD-8ED7-33AB8C63AFAF" type="groupchat"><body>Body Text</body><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="1233710-11447@chat.quickblox.com/89F03E1A-8FB0-47A4-9565-39D78C90E3C7" stamp="2014-08-12T19:45:10Z"/><x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" from="1233710-11447@chat.quickblox.com/89F03E1A-8FB0-47A4-9565-39D78C90E3C7" stamp="20140812T19:45:10"/></message>
```

Surprisingly, this is not as part of following delegate:

```
- (void)chatDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message
```

This is highly confusing...when will they get things into shape?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Chat 2.0 stuff?

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios

This is the modern way how to build Chat applications

It provides a better way to create a group chat than

```
[[QBChat instance] createOrJoinRoomWithName:roomName membersOnly:NO persistent:YES];
```